# Mongodb jsonschema with typescript

Tags: typescript, mongodb

I want to use mongodb $jsonshema validator with npm json-schema-to-typescript,
The problem is mongodb use bsontype instead of type and maybe there are more diffrences i dont know.
I can use json schema validator like ajv instead of mongodb validator but it will require me to implement validator at all places i insert or update data.
Is there a way to use mongodb jsonschema and also get interface from it.
I prefer not to relay on mongoose and orms.

Comment: What happens when you take the `$jsonschema` from your mongodb collection and pass it to `json2ts`?

Comment: I dk this libary but the main reason there is a problem is $jsonschema use bsontype where jsoschema use type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that you not generating typescript interface specs on the fly, so as long as you can extract the BSON schema from mongodb, then you just have to process it into "regular" JSON schema.  The bulk of the logic below is how to turn BSON types into (almost) equivalent JSON types

```js
db = db.getSiblingDB("testX");

function cvtb2j(holder, spot, value) {
    if(value == null) {
        return;
    }
    if(Array.isArray(value)) { // test FIRST since [] instanceof Object is true! 
        for(var jj = 0; jj < value.length; jj++) {
            cvtb2j(value, jj, value[jj]);
        }
    } else if(typeof value == "object") {
        walkObj(value);
    } else {
        if(spot == 'bsonType') {
            if(value == 'int' || value == 'long') {
                holder['type'] = 'integer';
            } else if(value == 'date') {
                holder['type'] = "string";
                holder['format'] = "date-time";
            } else if(value == 'decimal') {
                holder['type'] = "string";
                holder['format'] = "decimal";
            } else {
                holder['type'] = value;
            }
            delete holder['bsonType']
        }
    }
}

function walkObj(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
        cvtb2j(obj, k, obj[k]);
    });
}

vv = db.getCollectionInfos( { name: "myColl" } );
if(vv.length == 1) {
    vexpr = vv[0].options.validator;
    if(vexpr != undefined) {
        walkObj(vexpr);
        print(vexpr);
    }
}
```

An even more exciting approach would be to somehow make type handling pluggable in `json2ts` so that when it encountered unknown types like `date`, `decimal`, etc., a function could return the necessary type defs so that a fully formed interface could be emitted.

Comment: @nadav   I am 3 points shy of 7000.   How about accepting the answer and giving it a +1?